# angle to x-axis of a 3-d vector

Tags: vectors

I'm reviewing some basics in the textbook [Electromagnetics with Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070702403) and the worked problem 1-6-1 has some ambiguity i hope you can help me with.

The section is simply describing 3 dimensional vectors in Cartesian coordinates.  The text shows a figure that is very similar to the figure i show below (copied from [here](https://www.intmath.com/vectors/7-vectors-in-3d-space.php)).

[image]

The problem adds 2 vectors with a result of $\hat{x}10$ - $\hat{y}4$ + $\hat{z}0$.  It asks for the angle this vector makes with respect to the x-axis, $\alpha$.

I calculated it as $\alpha = cos^-{^1}\frac{10}{\sqrt{116}} = 21.8⁰$, but the textbook gives the answer as $\alpha=-21.8⁰$.

I think what they did was to actually calculate the angle to the x-axis that the ***projection*** of the vector makes with the x-y plane, which is clearly -21.8⁰.

FINALLY, my question:  What constitutes a negative angle $\alpha$ in the figure above?

Comment: If the question you mentioned is errorless then your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you SarGe.  Will the angle alpha ever be negative?  If so, what is it referenced to?

Comment: Angle $\alpha$ clockwise is equal to $\pi -\alpha$ anti-clockwise wrt $x$-axis.

Comment: I agree in regards to the x-y plane (or projection of the vector onto the x-y plane).  So looking at the figure i show above, what would be an example of alpha negative?  I don't understand how to reference "clockwise" as it relates to alpha in the figure....unless you are talking about the projection onto the x-y plane.

Comment: -@relayman357, you just have to measure the angle between the given line and $x$-axis. If the angle is obtuse, its $\cos$ will be negative.

Comment: I see, thank you.  When calculating the angle from the vector coordinates, how do I know when to assign the negative?

Comment: You don't have to worry about it. Just calculate $\vec v. \hat i=|\vec v|\cos \theta.$ If the angle is obtuse, then $\vec v. \hat i$ will automatically be a negative value.

Comment: So, in my question the vector is $\hat{x}10$ - $\hat{y}4 + \hat{z}0$.  So, $cos(\theta) = \frac{10}{\sqrt{116}}$. And, $\theta = cos^-{^1}\frac{10}{\sqrt{116}}$ = 21.8⁰.  How am i missing the negative?

Comment: As I said in the very first comment, if the vector you've calculated is correct then your answer is correct. It might be possible that the vector you calculated is wrong and hence you're getting wrong answer.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  It finally sinks in thick skull.  The only way to get a negative angle is for the $\hat {x}$ coefficient to be negative.  The answer in book is wrong in this context but correct if they are actually considering the projection of the vector onto the x-y plane.  Again, thank you.

Comment: Consider you've only $x$-axis and $\vec v$ and nothing else (consider them in one plane). Now, you just have to measure the angle ($\alpha$) between these two. If it is obtuse then its $\cos$ will be negative.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you've only $x$-axis and $\vec v$ and nothing else (consider them in one plane). Now, you just have to measure the angle ($\alpha$) between these two. If it is obtuse then its $\cos$ will be negative.